# Transparent Panels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am making a game where a user has to draw lines so as to make a ball bounce into a target. I'm having trouble getting both the ball and the line to show up concurrently, and I can get only one or the other to appear. It seems to me that the panels block each other out, even though I made them transparent. I would like for them both to appear on the same frame. As of this post, the line panel covers the ball panel.

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
  {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Let's Play");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        f.setSize(1280, 720);
        f.setLocation(300, 300);
        f.setResizable(false);

        //this part draws a ball that bounces around the screen
        BallPanel ballPanel = new BallPanel()
        {
           // draw rectangles and arcs

           public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
           {
            super.paintComponent(g); // call superclass's paintComponent 
            g.setColor(Color.red);

            // check for boundaries
            if (x < radius)         dx = Math.abs(dx);
            if (x > getWidth() - radius)    dx = -Math.abs(dx);
            if (y < radius)         dy = Math.abs(dy);
            if (y > getHeight() - radius)   dy = -Math.abs(dy);

            // adjust ball position
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
            g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius*2, radius*2);
           }

        };
        ballPanel.setOpaque(false);
        f.add(ballPanel);

        //this part allows you to draw lines on the frame with your mouse
        JPanel lineP = new JPanel()
        {
            Point pointStart = null;
            Point pointEnd   = null;

            {
                addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
                {
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) 
                    {
                        pointStart = me.getPoint();
                    }

                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) 
                    {
                        pointStart = null;
                    }
                });
                addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() 
                {
                    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) 
                    {
                        pointEnd = me.getPoint();
                    }

                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) 
                    {
                        pointEnd = me.getPoint();
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
            }
            public void paint(Graphics dline) 
            {
              super.paint(dline);
                if (pointStart != null) 
                {
                    dline.setColor(Color.RED);
                    dline.drawLine(pointStart.x, pointStart.y, pointEnd.x, pointEnd.y);

              }
            }
        };
        lineP.setOpaque(false); //attempted to enable to see ball panel here
        f.add(lineP);
        f.setVisible(true); 
    }
}

class BallPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
private int delay = 10;
protected Timer timer;

public int x = 30;      // x position
public int y = 30;      // y position
public int radius = 15; // ball radius

public int dx = 10;     // increment amount (x coord)
public int dy = 10;     // increment amount (y coord)

public BallPanel()
{
     timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    timer.start();      // start the timer
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
// will run when the timer fires
{
     repaint();
   }


}
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help ) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 2):

You've got several issues, but the main one is that you're over-using GUI components. You should have just one single component JPanel that does the drawing, a DrawingPanel, and not a ball panel and a line panel. Rather Ball and Line should be logical classes, not GUI classes, and their display should be in the same single DrawingPanel.

Other issues include:

- A main method that has way too much code. Most of that code should be off-loaded into the OOP world where it belongs.
- GUI component classes that also implement listener interfaces. This is giving the class too much responsibility making debugging and upgrading difficult. Separate these concerns.
- One of your classes overrides the paint method, and this should be avoided. Override paintComponent.
- The other class that overrides paintComponent has program logic within paintComponent, and this should be avoided since you have limited control over when or if this method gets called. Get the logic out of that class and into either the mouse listener code or the game loop code (Swing Timer).